# What am I? and Who is my maker?

Tags: riddle, rhyme

This should be a hard riddle.

> Three is the number of legs at this table,
>
> Three is where the arms are stable.
>
> Two is the boards to where you rest,
>
> Two is the curves the tires test.
>
> One is the line you repeat.
>
> Go! What am I? and who is my maker?

**Hint:**

> It's a feminine name!

Comment: *Once the heron, to set his path. Twice the heron, to name him true. Once the Dragon, for remembrance lost. Twice the Dragon, for the price he must pay.* (Sorry, your riddle just reminded me of this.)

Comment: Do three, two, and one represent the positions of characters in the solution of riddle?

Comment: @AJ No, it's not represent the positions of characters.

Comment: Each line might represent a letter, first two may be E and Y

Comment: @ArkaKarmakar You are on right track. E is right, but Y is wrong.

Comment: @rsp: (The puzzle which mirror was the answer) How the answer fitted with the last three lines ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The answer is:

> ELISE

Three is the number of legs at this table,

> E : represents a table with three legs (if you rotate it a bit).

Three is where the arms are stable.

> L: on a clock, arms(hands) are stable at 3.

Two is the boards to where you rest,

> I: I am not sure, but could be a bed upright (a bed is where we rest).

Two is the curves the tires test.

> S: represents a curvy road (guys, drive carefully).

One is the line you repeat.

> E: found at the first line

And who is my maker?

Well, I am not sure about that, but if you're:

> The [Lotus Elise](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lotus_Elise), then Lotus is your creator. (This is the first thing that comes up on google when typing "elise" ;-) ).

Comment: congrats! You got it...

Comment: Am I wrong to say "great [tag:lateral-thinking]"? Also, how about a (capital) I has a (horizontal) board on top, and one on the bottom?